# Adding number to variable in if else statement

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to add a number to a variable in an ifelse statement but the current code adds regarding of the if statement

```
for (i in 1:data)[1]{
data$new_variable[i] <- if(!is.na(data$variable_1[i]==1)){
data$variable_2[i] +15
}else{
data$variable_2[i]
}
}
```

My variable 1 has either 0 or 1 as a value (or NA) and I want to add 15 to variable_2 if variable_1 is 1.

Comment: `data$new_variable=ifelse(!is.na(data$variable_1==1),!is.na(data$variable_1==1)+15,!is.na(data$variable_1==1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
if(!is.na(data$variable_1[i]) & data$variable_1[i]==1){
  data$variable_2[i] = data$variable_2[i] + 15
}else{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, if I add your if statement to mine code I get what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In future please post your data:

```
data$new_variable <- ifelse(data$variable == 1, data$variable_2 + 15,  data$variable_2)
```